# Access another dictionary using same key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I got two dictionaries and both of them have same keys ,i am trying to access the second dictionary using the key as input of first dictionary like below

```
Players = {0: "Quit",
             1: "Player 1",
             2: "Player 2",
             3: "Player 3",
             4: "Player 4",
             5: "Player 5"
             }

exits = {0: {"Q": 0},
         1: {"W": 2, "E": 3, "N": 5, "S": 4, "Q": 0},
         2: {"N": 5, "Q": 0},
         3: {"W": 1, "Q": 0},
         4: {"N": 1, "W": 2, "Q": 0},
         5: {"W": 2, "S": 1, "Q": 0} }


 avabilablePlayer =",".join(list(Players.values()))
print (avabilablePlayer)


direction = input("Available Players are " + avabilablePlayer + " ").upper()
if direction in exits:
    dict_key=exits.get(direction)
    print(dict_key)
```

The above code is not returning the values from the second dictionary, how to fix this without using any methods and functions?

Comment: What are you putting in for `direction`?  The keys of `exits` are the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.  You'll get None if you try to use a different key, which is what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: what kind of output do you want.Can you show a sample?

Comment: @BrenBarn , edited the Players dictionary

Comment: @BrenBarn , both of them has  0,1,2,3,4,5 keys

Comment: @experiment , i will take input as  integer and will return the values from exit dictionary

Comment: @Karamzov  value in variable direction  will come out to be a string,first type cast it to int.I have posted the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here`s your solution

```
direction = input("Available Players are " + avabilablePlayer + " ").upper()
if int(direction) in exits.keys():
    dict_key=exits.get(int(direction))
    print(dict_key)
```

Comment: Can u  add , how to return if we pass the playername as input

Comment: @Karamzov if it works kindly upvote it and accept it! playername in what sense is it like passing the values of the players dict instead of keys?

Comment: @karamzov why are you becoming so selfish.The above code block does the work as asked in your question.Changing the requirements in the comment section wont help you in long run!

Comment: I was trying to understand the code and  so thats why i come up with another qustion

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to get the player index from the Players dictionary, then you can get the options from exits dictionary**

```
Players = {0: "Quit",
           1: "Player 1",
           2: "Player 2",
           3: "Player 3"
           }

exits = {0: {"Q": 0},
         1: {"W": 2, "E": 3, "N": 5, "S": 4, "Q": 0},
         2: {"N": 5, "Q": 0},
         3: {"W": 1, "Q": 0},
         4: {"N": 1, "W": 2, "Q": 0},
         5: {"W": 2, "S": 1, "Q": 0}}

avabilablePlayer = ",".join(list(Players.values()))
print(avabilablePlayer)

direction = input("Available Players are " + avabilablePlayer + " ").upper()

player_index = None

for key, value in Players.items():
    if direction == value.upper():
        player_index = key
        break

if player_index is None:
    print('Invalid Player')
else:
    dict_key = exits.get(player_index)
    print(dict_key)
```

Comment: i tried to run without player_index  `for key, value in Players.items():
       dict_key = exits.get(key)
      print(dict_key)`  , it not returning . whats the need for player_index here

Comment: @Karamzov you have player name in the direction variable. You don't have the integer index. So first you have to get the player_index.

Comment: what if i  only passed the integer as input ,  for player 1 = 1 , player 2= 2  , still not returning

Comment: @Karamzov did you check my solution?

Comment: My solution will work if you pas player name as input. But if you want to pass integer (index) then check the @experiment's solution.

Comment: In dictionary (Players or exits), you can't get the value unless you know the key. Since user pass the player name, we don't have the key (player index) but value (player name). That's why I have loop through entire Players dict and match with the user passed player name, if matched then we have the player_index. With player_index we can get the value from the exits dict